# CSS selector to get deepest element of specific class in the HTML tree

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've got a a bunch of DIV elements in my HTML, several of which have their class attribute set to "rowsLayout".  Some of these rowsLayout DIVs can be nested inside one another.  I want to define a CSS selector that only targets the deepest DIVs in those nestings.  That is, I **don't** want any of the rowsLayout DIVs that contain any other rowLayout DIVs.

```
<div id="a" class="rowsLayout">
  <div id="b" class="rowsLayout" />
  <div id="c" class="rowsLayout">
    <div id="d" class="rowsLayout" />
  </div>
</div>
<div id="e" class="rowsLayout" />
```

With this structure, I want a selector that will target b, d, and e.

Can this be done?

Comment: I don't think there's a CSS selector that can do this.

Comment: See my answer, the only hack that can do this. If you should is another question.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the jQuery selector `.rowsLayout:not(:has(.rowsLayout))`.

However, for performance reasons, [this is not possible in CSS](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors).

Your selector depends on the *children* (or lack thereof) of the elements that you target.
CSS is designed so that an element's selectors can always be resolved before the element's children exist; this allows CSS to be applied as a document loads.

Comment: This is not using css. This is using jQuery. Just to be clear. Question is about using CSS, which is not possible other than by using my noobs deleting my only correct answer utilizing the hack of :lang attribute.

Comment: is it possible to do this with vanilla JS and querySelector?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Your options are: select them by id; add a second class for those leaves, and select by that class; use a javascript-based solution to set the appropriate styling (possibly using the second class).

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question, but it's worth noting that the `:has` selector has now landed in browsers. So the JQuery solution can now be used as plain css

```
.rowsLayout:not(:has(.rowsLayout))
```

https://caniuse.com/css-has

Answer (score -1):

can you consider an option of adding an extra class such as "parent" to the parent items? it would be easier and is the *"standard"*

Comment: P.S. I suggested that but I don't really know how you're building your divs, is it dynamically?

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the number of divs you have you could either do something like:

```
div#b.rowsLayout,div#d.rowsLayout,div#e.rowsLayout {}
```

Maybe there is a better way to solve your problem, what are you trying to apply to all these divs?

Answer (score -2):

select them by ID

```
#b, #d, #e {
 /* styles here */
}
```

any reason for all the repeat class names btw? You could wrap the whole thing in div of #layout or something then do...

```
#layout div {
 /* styles */
}
```

instead of adding that class name to ever div.

Answer (score -3):

Why not use :empty?

[JQuery Empty](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-empty-selector-example/)

EDIT: It also works as a CSS Selector:

```
:empty { background-color: black; }
```

MORE EDITS:

`:last-of-type` almost works, but it gets 'a' for some reason. See my fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/DUdVR/3/

Comment: Note that that will only work in CSS 3. Also, it won't work for elements which have children, but not children of the required class.

Comment: True, but for the content provided it will work. If the OP wants us to provide perfect responses he should provide a complete example :)

Comment: Which is to say, browsers that support css 3. (and that won't affect it working in jquery).

Comment: Just another reason people need to leave IE in the trashbin where it belongs and move to Chrome (or Firefox or Safari or Opera)

Answer (score -3):

**MOST DOWNVOTES YET THE ONLY CORRECT ANSWER**

It is not possible in CSS, unless you use this hack, which makes it possible using the :dir or :lang attribute.

Using the :lang is preferable in 2015 as it is supported by most browsers.

**Note, it's a hack allowing you to do it, but if you care much about following some standard rather than getting the job done, then don't use this.**

Example:

```css
.container {
  padding:20px;
}

:lang(ar) {
  direction:rtl;
}

:lang(en) {
  direction:ltr;
}

.container:lang(en) {
  background-color:blue;
}

.container:lang(ar)  {
  background-color:red;
}

.container .a:lang(en)   {
  background-color:orange;
}

.container .a:lang(ar) {
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="searchHere">
  
    <div lang=en>      
      <div class="container">
          l t r
        <div class=a>
              a
         </div>
      </div>
      
      <div lang=ar>
          <div class="container">
             r t l
            <div class=a>
              a
              </div>
          </div>        
        
          <div>
            <div class="container">
                r t l 
              <div class=a>
              a
              </div>
            </div>  
            
            <div lang=ar>
                <div class="container">
                   r t l
                  <div class=a>
                    a
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
            
            <div lang=en>      
              <div class="container">
                  l t r
                <div class=a>
              a                  
              </div>
                
                <div lang=ar>
                  <div class="container">
                     r t l
                    <div class=a>
                      a                      
                      <div lang=en>      
                        <div class="container">
                          l t r
                          <div class=a>
                            a                  
                          </div>
                          <div>
                            <div>
                            
                              <div lang=en>      
                                <div class="container">
                                  l t r
                                  <div class=a>
                                    a                  
                                  </div>
                                </div>                      
                              </div>
                              
                              <div lang=ar>      
                                <div class="container">
                                  r t l
                                  <div class=a>
                                    a                  
                                  </div>
                                </div>                      
                              </div>
                              
                            </div>
                            
                          </div>
                        </div>                      
                      </div>
                  </div> 
                </div>
              </div>            
            </div>
            
          </div>
        
      </div>
      
    </div>
  
</div>
```

Although the example **demonstrates** this with **ltr** and **rtl**, the :**lang** could **in theory** be made to behave as a deepest match, using for instance :lang(**my-special-selector**) although that is **probably not how lang** attribute is supposed to be used.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question. It only introduces a non-related concept (languages)

Comment: it's the only answer that answers the question. yet the one with most downvotes.

Comment: you can put it in your favourite fiddle and you can see the result. how from css only i can declare a rule to apply to the deepest defined html.

Comment: This answer is not answering the question posted. The lang-attribute is only a declaration of the language of an object's content. You can use the CSS-selector `:lang()` to select for it; yes. But this has nothing to do with selecting leaf nodes of a dom.

Comment: I also state: 

Note, it's a hack allowing you to do it, but if you care much about following some standard rather than getting the job done, then don't use this.

Answer (score -3):

Take a look at this:

```
div#b:first-of-type {
style here
}
```