# Target the deepest nested ul/ol element with css

Tags: html, css

In a nested list like the one below, how would one target the ul containing `joe` without knowing the actual depth in advance?

```
<ul>
    <li>foo
        <ul>
            <li>bar
                <ul>
                    <li>baz
                        <ul>
                            <li>joe</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsbin.com/fiqowuhate/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: I feel this is not possible with just CSS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS selector to get deepest element of specific class in the HTML tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247888/css-selector-to-get-deepest-element-of-specific-class-in-the-html-tree)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I am personally aware, this is not possible as there is currently [no parent selector in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/1355856), but you could use the jQuery selector `$('ul:not(:has(ul))');` to target `ul` elements without any `ul` children, and add a class to them.

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2505L8p2/)

Comment: Great answer! This question got my head in a spin checking all the lastest possible selectors here for a possible answer. http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/

Comment: @Aaron Hey, thanks. The latest CSS selectors are great and I'm sure this would be possible one way or another but they always seem to be limited by browser support. Argh!

Answer (score 0):

**var str = $("ul>li:last").text();
alert("Deepest value :- " +str);**

Comment: This doesn't work if there are multiple elements at the top level: http://jsfiddle.net/5pmbed57/