# Selecting the last child with the given type among different levels of elements

Tags: html, css

I have a dynamically generated snippet of HTML which could look something like this (but may have many different levels of nesting):

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="thing"></div>
    <div>
        <div class="thing"></div>
        <div class="thing"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="thing"></div>
            <div class="thing"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="thing"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like a CSS expression to select the last element with the class `thing` that is a (not necessarily direct) child of `.content`.

`:last-child` or `:last-of-type` won't work because they match if the element is the last child (of a certain type) of their parent, in which case it will match more than `.thing`.

Is there a CSS expression I can use to do this?

Comment: Couldn't you just use `div div div:last-of-type` as your CSS selector?

Comment: No, because I don't know how deep the last `.thing` element is going to be.

Comment: Well, it could also be `div div:last-of-type`.  I don't know.  What do you think?  You could also just use IDs or `:nth-child()`.

Comment: The HTML is dynamically generated so I don't know how many layers deep or how many elements there will be in total, so I can't use any fixed hierarchy in the expression.

Comment: Have you tried `.thing:last-of-type` css selector?

Comment: @JohnReyM.Baylen Yes; as I mention in the question that doesn't work because it only selects the last **sibling**, and my `.thing`s aren't necessarily siblings.

Comment: @DanielGibbs Can you give the desired element an id or class when you generate it?

Comment: Not really no, as the `.thing`s are generated in different parts of the application so there's no way to know which is the last one.

Answer (score 1):

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247888/css-selector-to-get-deepest-element-of-specific-class-in-the-html-tree) suggest that this is not possible in CSS, unfortunately.