# How to select the deepest use of a CSS class?

Tags: html, css

How to select the deepest use of a css class?

In the following list, how do I select the deepest use of the class `.active`, in this case been the `<li>` wrapping `<span>Item 1.1.1.1</span>`?

```
<ul>
    <li class="active">
        <span>Item 1</span>
        <ul>
            <li class="active">
                <span>Item 1.1</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <span>Item 1.1.1</span>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="active"> // need selector for this <li>
                                <span>Item 1.1.1.1</span>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <span>Item 1.1.1.1.1</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span>Item 1.1.1.1.2</span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>Item 1.2</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <span>Item 1.2.1</span>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <span>Item 1.2.1.1</span>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <span>Item 1.2.1.1.1</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span>Item 1.2.1.1.2</span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<ul>
```

Comment: With depth it's not posibble in CSS if deep level is not constant. You have to do it in javascript. You can iterate trough specified node as long as it contains children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use jQuery `:not` and `:has` selectors like below to select the deepest active li:

```
$('li.active:not(:has(.active))')
```

### Explanation

`jQuery( ":not(selector)" )`: Selects all elements that do not match the given selector.

`jQuery( ":has(selector)" )`: Selects elements which contain at least one element that matches the specified selector.

### The results show:

```js
$('li.active:not(:has(.active))').css("border", "1px solid red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="active">
    <span>Item 1</span>
    <ul>
      <li class="active">
        <span>Item 1.1</span>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <span>Item 1.1.1</span>
            <ul>
              <li class="active">
                <span>Item 1.1.1.1</span>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <span>Item 1.1.1.1.1</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <span>Item 1.1.1.1.2</span>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Item 1.2</span>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <span>Item 1.2.1</span>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <span>Item 1.2.1.1</span>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <span>Item 1.2.1.1.1</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <span>Item 1.2.1.1.2</span>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <ul>
```

Comment: I just mentioned that element for illustration purpose. The deepest could be at any level of the hierarchical chain.

Comment: @ViniciusSantana OK, give you the dynamic way to get the deepest class.

Comment: @ViniciusSantana At present, pure html and css there is no way to achieve the goal, maybe someday new css version will appear the way, then I will update my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

That would be `ul .active .active .active li span`.

---

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247888/css-selector-to-get-deepest-element-of-specific-class-in-the-html-tree) answer you can't select it dynamically.

Use js/jQuery to find deepest node:

```
var deepest = null;
var depth = 0;

$('ul .active li').each(function () {
    if ($(this).parents('.active').length > depth) {
        depth = $(this).parents('.active').length;
        deepest = $(this);
    }
});
```

Comment: I just mentioned that element for illustration purpose. The deepest could be at any level of the hierarchical chain. Remove the first line and I'll accept your answer, even though in my case, this element is a react component and jquery is not an option, but I got the idea.

Comment: @ViniciusSantana In your question you do not mention that structure is dynamic. Also tags are only CSS and HTML

Comment: The question I asked is: How to select the deepest use of a css class?